# FromQuery parameters from camelCase/PascalCase to snake_case .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

I have tried the solution here: [How to properly set up snake case JSON for dotnet core api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353847/how-to-properly-set-up-snake-case-json-for-dotnet-core-api) but seems to be this is only for request/response payloads. Is there a way to force snake_case format on my [FromQuery] parameters?

Currently this is what I have as of the moment
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you did is about json serialization in asp.net core but what you want is to change the Swagger UI. They are the quite different things.

**The first way**, you can add attribute like: `[FromQuery(Name = "account_number")]`.

Or you can custom an attribute to avoid writing snake_case:

```
public class CustomFromQueryAttribute : FromQueryAttribute
{
    public CustomFromQueryAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name.ToSnakeCase();
    }
}
```

Custom `ToSnakeCase` for string extension:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToSnakeCase(this string o) =>
           Regex.Replace(o, @"(\w)([A-Z])", "$1_$2").ToLower();
}
```

Usage:

```
public voidGet([CustomFromQuery("AccountNumber")]string AccountNumber)
```

**Note:**

Actually this way equals to using `public voidGet(string account_number)`, so the Swagger UI changed.

---

**The second way**, you can custom `IOperationFilter` like below to change the Swagger UI:

```
public class SnakecasingParameOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null) operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();
        else { 
            foreach(var item in operation.Parameters)
            {             
                 item.Name = item.Name.ToSnakeCase();
            }              
        }
    }
}
```

Register the service like below:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.OperationFilter<SnakecasingParameOperationFilter>();
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApi5_0", Version = "v1" });
});
```

But this way change the request query string to snake case which has an extra `_`, It does not match the backend parameter. So you also need to custom value provider that looks for snake cased query parameters:

SnakeCaseQueryValueProvider:

```
 public class SnakeCaseQueryValueProvider : QueryStringValueProvider, IValueProvider
{
    public SnakeCaseQueryValueProvider(
        BindingSource bindingSource,
        IQueryCollection values,
        CultureInfo culture)
        : base(bindingSource, values, culture)
    {
    }

    public override bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        return base.ContainsPrefix(prefix.ToSnakeCase());
    }

    public override ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        return base.GetValue(key.ToSnakeCase());            
    }
}
```

We also have to implement a factory for our value provider:

```
public class SnakeCaseQueryValueProviderFactory : IValueProviderFactory
{
    public Task CreateValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        var valueProvider = new SnakeCaseQueryValueProvider(
            BindingSource.Query,
            context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        context.ValueProviders.Add(valueProvider);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Register the services:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ValueProviderFactories.Add(new SnakeCaseQueryValueProviderFactory()); //add this...
}).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
    };
});
```